# How do I host a website on VM running Tableau Server?

Tags: web, iis, hosting, tableau-api, windows-server-2016

I currently have an Azure VM running Windows Server 2016 hosting my Tableau Server. I want to add a simple website to the server through IIS that I can share files with my clients via a direct download link (e.g. a URL that would allow them to download a zip file, [www.mycompany.com/file.zip](http://www.mycompany.com/file.zip)).

Currently, when you visit my URL, it takes you to the Tableau Server instance. The website I want to add would basically be a subdirectory of that URL that hosts a file I have for my clients. So if my clients went to [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com), they would be taken to my Tableau Server. However if they went to [www.mycompany.com/files/](http://www.mycompany.com/files/), they would be allowed to download what ever file I attached to that URL.

I created a website under IIS Manager, but for the host name I am not allowed to use forward slashes. E.g. I want to create the website with the URL [www.mycompany.com/files/](http://www.mycompany.com/files/), but have to use [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) instead. I'm assuming I cannot use [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) for my host name, as that would conflict with my Tableau Server.

[image]

How then do I create a website in the manner I am describing? Or is it possible to somehow create a subdirectory within Tableau Server's structure?

Comment: I think you will have to configure IIS to listen on a different port (ie NOT port 80).  Tableau would have probably used port 80 when you installed it.  You can't have Tableau and IIS listening on the same port

Answer (score 0):

You can add virtual directory under website which host name is [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com).

Set physical path, alias to files. Then you can access it through [www.mycompany.com/files](http://www.mycompany.com/files).

[image]

Comment: When Tableau Server is installed, it does not add itself as a website under IIS, so I cannot add a virtual directory to it. I am assuming the website portion is done when Tableau Server is installed.

Comment: If tableau server is already bound to host name, all requests only get into it not IIS. Unless you set share files under tableau server.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about setting Tableau Server to share files since it is not listed under IIS?